# Do not remove duplicate values from array

Tags: php, download, zip, php-ziparchive

I have written this code to download files after adding them in a zip file. However, my code removes the files which have the same name ( duplicate ).

```
<?php
# define file array
$files = array(
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Physics.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Physics.PDF',
);

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="my file.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
?>
```

So my question is,

- How can I download duplicate files from an array?

or

- How can I change the names of duplicate files?

Comment: You are creating the duplicates yourself. So dont.

Comment: i know i want to download both files their file name is same but files are different.

Comment: So convert the URLs to valid filenames, or just use random filenames, or just use a counter for your filenames, or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename your files.

```
<?php
# define file array
$files = array(
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Physics.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Physics.PDF',
);

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Variable to Keep Filenames
$filename = '';
// Variable to add "-1, -2" to duplicate files
$i = 1;

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    if ( $filename == basename($file) )
    {
        // If this file already exists add "-1, -2"
        $filename = $i . '-' . basename($file);
        $i++;
    } else 
    {
        $filename = basename($file);
        $i = 1;
    }

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString($filename, $download_file);
}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="my file.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
?>
```

**Edit after @RiggsFolly Comment to support out of order duplicate files**

```
<?php
# define file array
$files = array(
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Chemistry.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2018/SSC-II/Physics.PDF', 
        'https://www.fbise.edu.pk/Old%20Question%20Paper/2017/SSC-II/Physics.PDF',
);

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Array to keep filenames
$filenames = array();

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    if( array_key_exists( basename($file), $filenames ) )
    {
        $filename =  $filenames[basename($file)] . '-' . basename($file);
        $filenames[basename($file)] = $filenames[basename($file)] + 1;
    } else
    {
        $filename = basename($file);
        $filenames[basename($file)] = 1;
    }

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString($filename, $download_file);
}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="my file.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
?>
```

Comment: This rather assumes that the duplicates are going to appear in a nice order one after another. What if the dups are file 1 and 4?

Comment: Thanks @shazyriver i am very thankful to you you solved my problem thanks bro.

Comment: But increment of number should be added before base name you mistakenly placed it after filename which changes the extension of file.

Comment: I have edited code to add fix according to RiggsFolly's comment.

Comment: Thanks @SoftWebTuts. I have re-edited the code. Please check if this is what you wanted.